# In Bayesian inference why is $E[\hat\Theta|X] = \hat\Theta$ ?!

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, expected-value, statistical-inference

https://youtu.be/XtNXQJkgkhI?t=1147

In this MIT video on Bayesian statistical inference, starting around the `19:07` mark, the professor claims that

$E[\hat\Theta|X] = \hat\Theta$

because $\hat\Theta$ is a function of $X$.

I feel this is a trivial argument but somehow I don't quite get it.

Could someone elaborate on that a bit?

Both $\hat\Theta$ and $X$ are uppercase here i.e.
the word is about random variables and not about concrete values of random variables.

Def. of what the $E[X|Y]$ means in the context of this course. It is a random variable by definition.

[image: definition]

Comment: if you know $X$ , and $\hat{\Theta} = f(X)$, then $\mathbb{E}[f(X)|X] = f(X) = \hat{\Theta}$. If you know $X$, then your best guess for $f(X)$ is $X$.

Comment: Yes, $ E[f(X)\mid X] = f(X).$ Intuitively, if you know $X,$ you know $f(X),$ and it is precisely the value we know $X$ to be, plugged into $f.$

Comment: @rubikscube09 It's not merely a best guess...

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen sure - it is the correct guess! But conditional expectation is usually phrased with the terminology "best-guess" so I wanted to be consistent with that.

Comment: @rubikscube09 In your initial note... is this a typo? Did you mean my best guess for $f(X)$ is $f(X)$ or is $X$?

Comment: @rubikscube09 ah I see what you're saying now.

Comment: @peter.petrov (they meant best guess for $f(X)$ is $f(X)$).

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen Yeah, so I thought. Thanks. But doesn't this require some more formal justification? I know, this video course is not so formal that's why I decided to ask here.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen E.g. isn't $\hat\Theta$ also a function of the prior distribution of $\Theta$? Why can we claim is purely a function of $X$. I feel like something is oversimplified here.

Comment: @peter.petrov Your question is as simple as $E[f(X) \mid X] = f(X)$. Regarding your question about the prior distribution, note that $X$ depends on the prior distribution as well. In fact, the equation implies that $X$ contains all the information about the prior that $\hat{\Theta}$ needs.

Comment: The easiest justification is done using (not very hard to understand) concepts from measure theory - are you familiar with it?

Comment: @rubikscube09 Sort of familiar. I've read a thing or two about Lebesque measure and all that.

Comment: I've posted the formal definition. It is from this book. Page 222 https://www.amazon.com/Introduction-Probability-2nd-Dimitri-Bertsekas/dp/188652923X

Comment: @rubikscube09 How do you prove what you stated in your first comment, that $E[f(X)|X] = X$ ? See also: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3907123/how-do-we-prove-formally-that-ehx-x-hx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best way to understand this segment of the lecture is to extend the particular example that was discussed, to explicitly calculate the estimator $\hat \Theta$.  Rather than using increasing levels of abstraction or formalization, we seek to illuminate by making the example more concrete.

Recall in the previous portion of the lecture that the model is $$\Theta \sim \operatorname{Uniform}(4,10), \\ X \mid \Theta \sim \operatorname{Uniform}(\Theta - 1, \Theta + 1).$$  The joint density has value $1/12$ over its support, which is a parallelogram:  $$f_{\Theta, X}(\theta, x) = \frac{1}{12} \mathbb 1(4 \le \theta \le 10) \mathbb 1(\theta - 1 \le x \le \theta + 1).$$  This parallelogram is bounded by the lines $$\theta = x-1, \quad \theta = x+1, \quad \theta = 4, \quad \theta = 10.$$
When $5 \le X \le 9$, the conditional expectation $\operatorname{E}[\Theta \mid X]$ is just the midpoint between $X+1$ and $X-1$; i.e., $\operatorname{E}[\Theta \mid X] = X$.  In other words, in this interval, the conditional expectation is just the parallel line between the aforementioned boundaries $\theta = x-1$ and $\theta = x+1$; i.e., $\theta = x$.
However, when $3 \le X < 5$, we have to take the midpoint between $\theta = x+1$ and $\theta = 4$; i.e., $$\operatorname{E}[\Theta \mid X] = \frac{X+1+4}{2} = \frac{X+5}{2}.$$  And when $9 < X \le 11$, we similarly have $$\operatorname{E}[\Theta \mid X] = \frac{X-1+10}{2} = \frac{X+9}{2}.$$  All together, $$\hat \Theta = \operatorname{E}[\Theta \mid X] = \begin{cases}\frac{X+5}{2}, & 3 \le X < 5 \\ X, & 5 \le X \le 9 \\ \frac{X+9}{2}, & 9 < X \le 11. \end{cases}$$  You will note that this is a continuous but not everywhere differentiable function.  More importantly, you will also note that $\operatorname{E}[\Theta \mid X]$ is a random variable that is solely a function of $X$, and it seeks to *estimate* $\Theta$ through the observed $X$.  Hence $\hat \Theta = \operatorname{E}[\Theta \mid X]$ is what he calls the least mean squares estimator.

The essential claim that you have questioned is $\operatorname{E}[\hat \Theta \mid X] = \hat \Theta$.  But we now see from the above example what the professor means: if $X$ is given, then $\hat \Theta$ is no longer random with respect to $X$.  You know it, and its expected value is again a function of the conditional $X$.  Moreover, it is unchanged.  For instance, if I ask for $\hat \Theta \mid (X = 8)$, you would give me $8$.  Taking the conditional expectation of $\hat \Theta$ given $X$ doesn't modify the estimate.

Another way to think of it is to suppose I let $h(X) = X^2$.  Then what is $\operatorname{E}[h(X) \mid X = x]$?  Well, it is just $\operatorname{E}[X^2 \mid X = x] = \operatorname{E}[x^2] = x^2$.  Similarly, $\operatorname{E}[X^2 \mid X] = X^2$.  And $\operatorname{E}[h(X) \mid X] = h(X)$.  So $\operatorname{E}[\hat \Theta \mid X] = \hat \Theta$.

Comment: Thanks, I will read your answer thoroughly. But the equality $E[\hat\Theta|X] = \hat\Theta$ is not specific to this example. It is valid in general for the optimal LMS estimator which is defined as $\hat\Theta = E[\Theta|X]$.

Comment: @peter.petrov I am simply using the example to assist in illustrating what $\hat \Theta \mid X$ means.  Read the last paragraph of my answer.

Comment: Yeah... I see. OK, thanks.

Comment: I keep rereading and rethinking this but the last paragraph is not really a formal proof. How do we prove formally that: $E[h(X) | X] = h(X)$ for any function $h$? Maybe I will just ask another question.

Comment: @peter.petrov you can look at my answer and it should make sense from my definition of conditional expectation that this is the case.

Answer (score 1):

Let $X$ be a random variable mapping into the real numbers on a probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$, and assume that $X \in L^2(\Omega)$ ($X$ has a well defined variance/second moment.

**Definition:** We say that a random variable $Y$ is $X$-*measurable* if there exists a Borel-measurable, deterministic, function $f : \mathrm{Range(X)} \to \mathbb{R}$ such that:
$$
Y = f(X)
$$
almost-surely. This basically means that $Y$ is completely determined by $X$ - up to a deterministic transformation. This is sort of the *opposite* of saying that $X$ is independent of $Y$, or vice-versa.

**Definition**: For an $L^2$ random variable $Z$, we define the random variable:
$$
\mathbb{E}[Z|X] \equiv f_Z(X)
$$
to be the unique (almost - surely) random variable such that:

1. $\mathbb{E}[Z|X]$ is $X$ measurable - so $\mathbb{E}[Z|X]$ is given by a deterministic transform of $X$ (this transformation depends on $Z$ of course as you'll see in the next line).
2. $\mathbb{E}[Z|X]$ minimizes the *mean square error*:
   $$
   \mathbb{E}[ (Z - g(X))^2]
   $$
   over all possible borel-measurable deterministic functions $g$ (equivalently - all $X$-measurable random variables).

Thus, the conditional expectation can be interpreted as the unique deterministic transformation of $X$ that minimizes the mean squared error amongst all such deterministic transformations (Borel-measurable of course).

The general definition of measurability is more abstract/harder to motivate in general, but my biggest breakthrough in probability was that if $Y$ is $X$ measurable and $Y$ and $X$ are random variables, then $Y,X$ are related by a deterministic transform. This doesn't go both ways, for example if $Y = X^2$, then knowing $X$ gives you the value of $Y$, but knowing $Y$ does not uniquely specify $X$.